# Editing of a csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have generated a csv file and it looks like this:

```
50,57,13,10,50,48,13,10,49,55,13,10,49,54,13,10,49,52,13,10,49,52,13,10,49,50,13,10,49,49,13,10

49,49,13,10,57,13,10,57,13,10,57,13,10,56,13,10,56,13,10,55,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54

13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,53,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,54,13,10,53,13,10

53,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,53,13,10,53,13,10,53,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13

10,52,13,10,53,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51

13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,53,13,10

53,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13

10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51

13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10

52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,50,13,10,51,13,10,51,13

10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51

13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,53,13,10,52,13,10

52,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,52,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,51,13,10,52,13
```

I want to reframe it to such that it should have one row only and no columns at all. I tried `numpy.genfromtxt`

```
new=np.genfromtxt('repaired.csv', dtype='float', delimiter=',', skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None, missing_values=None, filling_values=None, usecols=None, names=None, excludelist=None, deletechars='"', replace_space='_', autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt='f%i', unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True, max_rows=None)
```

but it didn't work. I am geting error as:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #1591 (got 28 columns instead of 32)
    Line #1593 (got 4 columns instead of 32)
```

Comment: Seems like some of your rows might be a few columns short - can you navigate to the lines specified in the file and see if they are formatted correctly?

Comment: do you want as a `list`?

Comment: the error message could not be any clearer... make sure that all your rows have the same length,

Comment: Actually i wanted it to be stored as a numpy array

Comment: @ hiro protagonist I know, just tell me a way i can avoid those lines with diffrent no.of columns . I tried with **footer** but it is not woking.Thanks

Comment: find and replace the line feeds with nothing, split on comma and convert the returned list into a numpy array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done all this way to convert the `csv` file into `numpy array`

```
import csv
import numpy as np
data_in_csv_file = []
# reading the csv file
with open('hello2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data_in_csv_file.append(row)
# removing the empty row of the csv file
# and convert into a list
list_values = sum(data_in_csv_file,[])
# converting numpy array
values = np.array(list_values)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have the possibility to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can try this:

```
import pandas

new = pandas.read_csv('repaired.csv', sep=',', engine='python', header=None)
```

the first line in your csv must be amongst the longest lines though, otherwise this will not work either.

if you need your data as pure `numpy` array you can convert it:

```
nm = new.as_matrix()
```